# Neo4j How can I return both node and relationship?

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

I am using `Neo4jClient` to write a demo. My demo has two nodes : *Beer* and *BeerBrand* and one relationship Is_Made has *propertise ReleaseDay*. I wrote this code to get nodes *BeerBrand* which made specific beer.

```
var isMadeBy = beer
                .StartCypher("b")
                .Match("b-[r:IS_MADE]->e")
                .Return<Node<BeerBrand>>("e")                
                .Results.ToList();
```

Now, I want to get relationship *Is_Made*

```
var isMadeBy = beer
                .StartCypher("b")
                .Match("b-[r:IS_MADE]->e")
                 .Return<Relationship<IsMade>>("r")
                .Results.ToList();
```

But, errors were thrown that

```
class IsMade must be non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor 
in order to use it as parameters 'TData' in the generic type or 
method 'Neo4jClient.Relationship<TData>'
```

Can you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: What version of Neo4J are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at the wiki? http://hg.readify.net/neo4jclient/wiki/cypher

If you don't need the relationship Id then give that a try:

```
var isMadeBy = beer
     .StartCypher("b")
     .Match("b-[r:IS_MADE]->e")
     .Return((r, e) => new {
          isMadeRelationship = r.As<Node<SomeObjectWithAPublicConstructor>>()
          beerBrand = e.As<Node<BeerBrand>>()
      })
      .Results.ToList();
```

Comment: I applied your code but It thrown an error : [MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.]

Comment: It was close you needed to have an object with a public constructor. Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

There is an answer to a similar question here: [Neo4jClient - Retrieving relationship from Cypher query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574518/neo4jclient-retrieving-relationship-from-cypher-query) which will give you the guide you should follow.

In essence, you need to add a Parameterless constructor to your relationship to allow the client (and in particular - JSON.NET) to be able to deserialize your relationship from what is in the DB to your code. Basically - JSON.NET can't figure out how to construct your relationship, as it doesn't know what the parameters in your constructors relate to.

You may also need to change from returning 'Relationship' to 'RelationshipInstance'.