# Retrieving relationships using neo4j C# client

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

I want to retrieve a relatioship between nodes using C# neo4j client.

using this query:

```cs
var lastRel = myGraphClient.Cypher
              .Start(new { parent = parentRouteNode })
              .Match("(parent)-[lastR:LAST]->(child)")
              .Return(lastR => lastR.As<Relationship<Last>>()).Results;
```

I am able to return the parent and child nodes in a similar way, but for relationships,
i get the following exception:

"Neo4jClient encountered an exception while deserializing the response from the server. This is likely a bug in Neo4jClient."

Is this really a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you post the REST raw response? Would be good to see the underlying exception in there from the server.

Answer (score 1):

Use `RelationshipInstance<T>` instead of `Relationship<T>` when you retrieveng relationships.

```cs
var lastRel = myGraphClient.Cypher
              .Start(new { parent = parentRouteNode })
              .Match("(parent)-[lastR:LAST]->(child)")
              .Return(lastR => lastR.As<RelationshipInstance<Last>>()).Results;
```

See here: [Retrieving relationship from Cypher query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574518/neo4jclient-retrieving-relationship-from-cypher-query)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use any wrapper type:

```
var lastRel = myGraphClient.Cypher
    .Start(new { parent = parentRouteNode })
    .Match("(parent)-[lastR:LAST]->(child)")
    .Return(lastR => lastR.As<Last>())
    .Results;
```